# how can i login through Snapchat in my web application and get user details like username, unique_id, and name in Asp.net C#

Tags: authentication, snapchat

How can I provide the functionality to log in through Snapchat in my website and get user details like `username`, `unique_id`, and `name` in Asp.net C#?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they have a library to do so in `Asp.net` but for Node.js they do have what you are looking for and this is an official library from their github account

https://github.com/Snapchat/passport-snapchat